# Activeadmin import or upload image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I need to upload an image to my activeadmin without using any gem. These are my code.
app/admin/article_month.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register ArticleMonth do
menu label: "Month", parent: "News Digest"



    permit_params :month, :year, :image, :published_at

  index do
    selectable_column
    column :month
    column :year
    column :image
    column :published_at
    actions
  end
 form multipart: true do |f|
    f.inputs do 
        f.input :month, :as => :select, :collection => ["January", "February", 
            "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
            "October", "November", "December"]
        f.input :year
        f.input :image, :as => :file
        f.input :published_at, :as => :date_picker
    end
    f.actions
 end


end
```

but it returns an error like this:

```
NoMethodError in Admin::ArticleMonthsController#create
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

I don't know where 'name' came from. 
Is there any way to solve my problem? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

this code works on me:)

```
 form multipart: true do |f|
    f.inputs do 
        f.input :month, :as => :select, :collection => ["January", "February", 
            "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
            "October", "November", "December"]
        f.input :year
        f.input :image, input_html: { type: :file, class: "default"}, wrapper: false
        f.input :published_at, :as => :date_picker
    end
    f.actions
 end
```